# How to get the location of the center of animating circle in Raphael js?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I use raphael js to draw a circle and I use `Element.animate()` to make the circle move around a position. But I found it is not that easy to get the real time coordinate of the circle, when I use `circle.animate()`, I found the `circle.attr('cx')` and `circle.attr('cy')` is still same even though it is animate.

So is there any way to track coordinate of center of the animating circle?

Comment: I would include some code. Its not clear what attribute you are animating. If you are animating cx/cy they should be different. If you are animating by transforming it, they would remain the same and it makes a bit more complex (but then. why not just animate cx,cy)

Comment: Yes, I use transform attribute to do the animate. So that it makes the circle's cx and cy remain the same. How can I animate cx and cy in Raphael js to make it looks same as using transform attribute?

Comment: Can you not do element.animate({ cx: 100 }, 1000) for example ?